# submit button on hover isn't working

Tags: php, html, css, loops, hover

I'm working on a newsfeed and I have a while loop for every posts with the styles, but then I created an

`<input type="submit" name="deletePost" value="Delete" class="delete_post" />`

and with the styling it isn't working... well the styling works but the `:hover` isn't working. Nor the `:active` and others. Very strange.

**CSS**

```
.image_post .user_avatar {
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.image_post .user_avatar img {
    width:32px;
    min-height:32px;
}
.image_post .user_name {
    margin-top:7px;
    color:#fc0096;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.image_post .timeago {
    color:#999;
    font-size:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
}
.image_post img {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.image_description {
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:8px;
    background:white;
    text-align:left;
    color:#000;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
.image_post input[type="submit"] {
    border:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:10px;
    background:black;
    padding:0;
    margin:6px 0 0 0;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:9px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    z-index:999;
}
.image_post input[type="submit"]:hover {
    cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

**HTML INSIDE PHP WHILE LOOP**

```
    <div class="image_post">
    <input type="submit" name="deletePost" value="Delete" class="delete_post" />
    <div class="user_avatar">
        <img src="avatars/'.$pica['username'].'.jpeg" />
    </div>
    <div class="user_name">'.$pica['username'].'</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="timeago">'.$diff.'</div>
    <div class="image_description">'.$pica['description'].'</div>
    <img src="upload/'.$pica['name'].'" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I really don't understand why the `:hover` isn't working. It does take the styles from the normal one, but then the `:hover`, `:active` etc isn't working. I'm struggling with this and it's really weird, because I do html/css for 2 years, every day. I tried a lot of possible solutions, but sadly... they failed. Even in pencode / jsfiddle it failed with the cursor:pointer ;/

Comment: worked for me: http://jsbin.com/jipadowo/1/edit - perhaps you overwrite your css-style somewhere in your code

Comment: Did a quick test too, and it works. Only cursor pointer on hover, right?

Comment: Works as you would expect it to. See here ->http://jsfiddle.net/MGPB4/

Comment: Maybe you have some spelling mistake (typo) in your code, I just copy-pasted this code and it works!!

Answer (score -1):

Even tho it's weird... try using the class like `.delete_post:hover` on your CSS instead of `input[type="submit"]:hover`.

I think that should work fine. If not, try placing and ID for it and try with the ID like `.image_post #delete_post:hover`.

Since it's super weird because it should work fine... maybe you can try jQuery and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete_post").hover(function(){
        $(this).attr("style","cursor:pointer;");
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
    });
});
```

But again... I don't see why `:hover` is not working for you.

Comment: I did but I output it with `while($pica = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}` so it comes from the database and even if I put a link around everything, it isn't linking so I think it has something to do with the database output.

Comment: If it has to do with the database, then why not trying with ``fetch_array()``? But I don't know, it's just weird because if the CSS is working, I don't see why the pseudo class is not...